# I am not able to write whitespace separated string into a file in C using fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite

Here I want to write string str into the file `log.dat`. I am facing problems when the `str` has whitespace in between words.

In that case data is not written to the file properly and some characters go missing.

My code to write:

```
fp=fopen("log.dat","ab");
fwrite(str,1,sizeof(str),fp);
```

And to read:

```
char c;
fp = fopen("log.dat", "rb");
c = fgetc(fp);
while (c != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
    c = fgetc(fp);
}
```

I dont want to read the last character of file, how can I implement that?

I'd also like to check if there is no data inside file, how can I implement that functionality?

Comment: `sizeof(str)` is sizeof of a pointer is probably  8. Maybe you want `strlen(str)` instead?

Comment: @pmg that really helped. But now when I am reading from the file, I am not getting spaces after end of 1 string.

Comment: Why not `fgets()` and `fprintf()`? The low-level `fread()` and `fwrite()` are more difficult to use.

Comment: @havegudday you must use `int` with `fgetc`.

Comment: After each and every `fopen` you absolutely need to check if `fopen` failed. There is no excuse of not doing it such as "I know the file exists" etc.

Comment: @havegudday next time [edit] your question instead of putting code in a comment. As you can see, code in comments is not very readable.

Answer (score 2):

There are some things we don't know about your code that can fail or cause undefined behavior, for example, are you closing the file before opening it to read?

This is why it's important to post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

That being the case, here is, generically, how you should do it:

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/WatchfulPeacefulLine)</kbd>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *str = "this is my string,";
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("log.dat", "ab");

    if (fp == NULL){ //check for fopen failure
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int num_chars = 0;
    if((num_chars = fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), fp)) == 0){ //no data was written
        puts("No data was written to the file."); //you can adapt check to your needs
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(fp); //close fp

    fp = fopen("log.dat", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL){ //check for fopen failure
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int c;
    int i = 0;
    char string[num_chars];
    int count_chars = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {//read until end of file 
        count_chars++; //count characters
        //printf("%c", c); 
        string[i++] = c; //assign the string, it's much easier to remove the last char
    }
    
    if(i > 0)
        string[i - 1] = '\0'; //overwrite last char with a null byte

    if(count_chars == 0){ // if count is 0 file has nothing
        puts("File is empty");
    }
    else{
        printf("\n%d characters were read\n", count_chars);
        puts(string);
    }
}
```

Some of these variables duplicate values, `strlen(string)`, `count_chars` and `num_chars` should have the same value, but they are purposefully diferenciated to simulate a real program scenario where read and write errors can occur.

Comment: @havegudday what's the point of not wanting to read the last character. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have user comma after each string. So I dont want to print the final comma

Comment: @havegudday what's wrong with simply not printing the char if it's a comma?

Answer (score 1):

**Off topic**

You should replace this awkward code:

```
c = fgetc(fp);
while (c != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
    c = fgetc(fp);
}
```

with this:

```
while ((c = fgets(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

Always try to avoid useless repetitions.

**Less off topic:**

`fgetc` returns an `int`, not a char, therefore you need to declare `int c;` instead of `char c;`

Comment: if i want to skip last character of a file while printing and also give the message that file is empty if there is no data inside the file, How can i implement that?? @Jabberwocky

Comment: @havegudday Sorry, but I didn't get your question. But anyway, you should ask an all new question.

Comment: pls help with: 1.How to print characters of the file except the final character?. 2.How to check If there is no content inside the file

Comment: That should be a new question.